# PPS ioctl failure in GPS

Tags: pi-2, linux, raspbian-jessie, gps

I am using U-Blox AG GPS in my Raspberry pi 3. My GPS had a fix and displayed all the data in a right way. After an hour of working, it is not getting a fix. So I checked the gpsd status. It displayed an error as follows:

```
gpsd[2124]: gpsd:ERROR: PPS ioctl(TIOCMIWAIT) failed: 25 Inappropriate ioctl 
for device
```

The full detail is as follows:

```
service gpsd status
gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; static)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-07-19 10:49:38 IST; 5min ago
Main PID: 2124 (gpsd)
CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
       └─2124 /usr/sbin/gpsd -N -n -G -b /dev/ttyACM0

Jul 19 10:49:38 Busplay2 systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) 
Daemon.
Jul 19 10:49:39 Busplay2 gpsd[2124]: gpsd:ERROR: PPS ioctl(TIOCMIWAIT) 
failed: 25 Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What is PPS ioctl? What's the issue here?

The hardware setup for this is a raspberrypi with a usb hub which has a wifi dongle and a 4g device. Will the sharing of the usb cause this issue?

Suggestions Welcome.

Comment: *"In computing, ioctl (an abbreviation of input/output control) is a system call for device-specific input/output operations and other operations which cannot be expressed by regular system calls."* [WikipediA - ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl). Seems there is something wrong with your hardware.

Comment: Not necessarily; it could be the software is mismatched with the hardware. *"Will the sharing of the usb cause this issue?"* -> I guess the best way to find out is to try it without that.  You could be pulling a bit too much current, which might cause  random failures with the peripherals.